# How to fix this jQuery/coffeescript code for jquery-ui autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, autocomplete, coffeescript

Hi so I have code like for jquery-ui 1.11:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#search_terms').autocomplete
    source: (request, response) ->
      $.ajax
        url: '/list.json'
        dataType: "json"
        data: { term: request.term }
        success: (data) ->
          response: $.map(data, (v, i) ->
            label: i
            value: v.toString()
          )
```

If I do  `console.log $.map(data, (v, i)...` I get this output in Firebug console window: `[Object {label="someX", value="someY"}, Object....]`

How do I fix the `$.map` code to get the right JSON format for jquery ui autocomplete?

Adding `JSON.stringify` around the `$.map` code yields something like:

`[{"label":"Label1","value":"5"}, ...]`  which seems like it should work but does not.  Not sure if it's because I have Twitter Bootstrap 3 enabled...

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery autocomplete widget expects you to [return an array of strings to offer to the user](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default). If you want the values to be offered to the user, you can transform your array like this:

```
$.map(data, (v, k) ->
  v.toString()
)
```

Or - as seems more likely - if you want the labels to be offered to the user, you can transform your array like this:

```
$.map(data, (v, k) ->
  k
)
```

Which is equivalent to [`data.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

You must call the response function, too; I think your CoffeeScript returns an object with one key, `response`. So your overall CoffeeScript should be along these lines:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#search_terms').autocomplete
    source: (request, response) ->
      $.ajax
        url: '/list.json'
        dataType: "json"
        data: { term: request.term }
        success: (data) ->
          response data.keys()
        error: response []
```

(I've added an `error` callback because the documentation says [you must call `response` even in the case of an error](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source).)

Finally, you may be able to simplify this. If you modify your server so a request like `list.json?term=search` returns a JSON array of strings, then your autocomplete could be as simple as:

```
jQuery -> 
  $('#search_terms').autocomplete
    source: "/list.json"
```